# How can I add a conditional class to multiple elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am a total n00bie here, so please excuse any errors/issues I have made with this or any etiquette faux pas!

I am looking to build some nice, easy to touch buttons for radio inputs on a form that is using field yields. The idea being they are greyscaled at first and upon hover & selection, they lose the greyscale and reveal the colour beneath.

As I am sure you can see, I have hacked around at code I have found on here to try and get this to all work. Despite not having worked with jQuery before, the below code actually functions as I want to too.

I just need the query to apply the **.active** class to a second element (the label with the class **.icon** )

Please find below the code I am using.

**CSS**

```
input[type='radio']:checked{
        positon:absolute;
     -webkit-filter: brightness(1.1) grayscale(0) opacity(1)!important;
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.1) grayscale(0) opacity(1)!important;
            filter: brightness(1.1) grayscale(0) opacity(1)!important;
    }

.drinkcard-cc:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
            filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);

}
.drinkcard-cc:checked{
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(0);
       -moz-filter:grayscale(0);
            filter:grayscale(0);

} 

.drinkcard-cc{
    cursor:pointer;
    padding: 45px;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
     -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.8);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.8);
            filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.8);
            border-radius: 10px;  

.active{
-webkit-filter: brightness(1.1) grayscale(0) opacity(1)!important;
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.1) grayscale(0) opacity(1)!important;
            filter: brightness(1.1) grayscale(0) opacity(1)!important;
            border: 1px solid #007bff;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  makeActive();
  $("input[type='radio']").on("change",function(){
    makeActive();
  });
});
function makeActive(){
  $("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
      if($(this).prop("checked")){
        $(this).closest('.option').addClass("active");

      }else{
        $(this).closest('.option').removeClass("active");

      }
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-12 d-block mx-auto">                             
<h3> Are you Male or Female? </h3>
<div class="cc-selector grid-container">
{{#options}}
<div class="drinkcard-cc option">
        <label class="drinkcard-cc icon" id="{{value_id}}" for="{{field_id}}_{{value_id}}"/></label>
        <label class="label-text" for="{{field_id}}_{{value_id}}" data-db-localized-content="{{field_id}}_OPTION_{{value_id}}" ></label>
        <input 
            class="image-input drinkcard-cc"
            type="radio" 
            id="{{field_id}}_{{value_id}}"
            name="{{name}}" 
            value="{{value}}" />
</div>
    {{/options}}
</div>
</div>
```

So currently the query adds the **.active** class to the element with the class **#option** - I would also like to apply this to **#icon**

I have tried re-writing this as parent/child and it loses the functionality of the checked radio button and applies the class to every div element (condensed)

```
var parent ='div'
var child = 'label'

function makeActive(){
$("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
if($(this).prop("checked")){
$(parent).addClass("active");
$(parent +child).addClass("active");
$(parent +child +child).addClass("active");

}else{
$(parent).removeClass("active");
$(parent +child).removeClass("active");
$(parent +child +child).removeClass("active");
```

I have tried adding:

```
$("#ICON").addClass("active") or .removeClass
```

to the relevant parts of the "if/else" parts; However, this does not seem to work.

I am certain the solution is really simple, I am just frazzled from looking at this for so long!

Comment: Why - just to apply formatting to .icon? That doesn’t need the class added to that element, you already added it to its ancestor, so you can use the descendant selector in CSS to format it based on that. `.drinkcard-cc.active .icon { /* beautiful formatting here */ }`

Comment: Perfect... I was using :active but .active works a treat! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all for their comments -

The simplest answer was to create the extra css class:

`.drinkcard-cc.active .icon { /* beautiful formatting here */ }`

Thank you to 04FS for this!

I will in due course try the JS responses - Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
function makeActive(){
   $("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
      var div = $(this).closest('.option');
      if($(this).prop("checked")){
         div.addClass("active").find('.icon').addClass("active");             
      }else{
         div.removeClass("active").find('.icon').removeClass("active");
      }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You were too close you had just to use the class notation `.icon` instead of the id notation `#icon`.

Try using:

```
$(".icon").addClass("active")
```